# How to reduce the difference in color between stitched images to make a smooth color transition?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision

I'm stitching multiple images, and I want to improve the color transition between them. Here are the two images:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbfUE.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nFs1.jpg

And here's the stitched images:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/l60La.jpg

As you can probably see, the color transition is extremely poor. I want to make it look like they're the same images (or at least close to it)

The way I'm currently doing it:

I first remove the seam using `filter2D` and then obtain the mask of the points where the images join using Laplacian transform, and using this mask, I do inpainting like so:

Seam removal:

```
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/25
seam_removal = cv2.filter2D(data_map,-1,kernel)
```

And here's the mask I obtain of the points where the images join, and using this I do inpainting after a bit of dilation:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/YocNO.jpg

But as you can see in the final image, that does not improve the blending at all.

Comment: the most common approach is probably poisson blending (you can look here: http://www.learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp/ )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is a good idea or not, but I think you can use [**Kmeans**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) to "tune" the color of the image.

**First**, you convert your images into **RGB**

```
image= cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

**Second**, train the first image with **Kmeans** algorithm and find out the "cluster color"

```
clt = KMeans(n_clusters = 20)
clt.fit(img1)
colors = clt.cluster_centers_
```

**Third**, by using the **cluster colors** found in step 2 to convert the color in image 2. You may refer to this [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_color_quantization.html).

**Finally**, just combine the two images into one.

And I have second approach, that is you can change both images tone into the same tone. You can take a look **[here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/df0/tutorial_py_hdr.html#gsc.tab=0)**.